# WordPress Setting up Domain Routing on New Box From Existing Site

Tags: wordpress

I have a WordPress site on my server that I moved from another box by copying and pasting the WP directory.  I've changed the database info so that the new site is pulling from a replicated database.  When I access my new WP site now, I noticed that all of the links are still pointing to the domain of the old site.  For example if I click on "Contact", the browser goes to "www.olddomain.com/contact" instead of "www.newdomain.com/contact".

How do I reroute all of my links to the new server / domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the new domain as a DEV box.  I ended up changing the hosts file.  Mapped all requests from www.olddomain.com to www.newdomain.com

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there's an *easy* way to fix that.

If you have phpMyAdmin installed, just do a search for your old domain in the database, and just replace it with the new domain anywhere it appears.